# Как переключиться между компонентами-приложеняими в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Я создал 2 js файла на реакте. Один предназначен для гостей сайта, другой для авторизированного пользователя. То есть грубо говоря 2 приложения,в каждом роутер и странички. в html у меня подключен только 1 файле  рендерится он:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function func(){
      function isAuthorized(){
          return document.cookie.indexOf('cookie')===0;
      }
      if(isAuthorized()) {
         var s = document.createElement("script");
             s.src = "app2.js";
             s.id = "index_js";
             document.getElementById("app_container").innerHTML = "";
             document.getElementById("app_container").appendChild(s);
      }
    }

  </script>

  <div id="app_container">
        <script id="index_js" src="app.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Я думал переключаться между этими файлами используя проверку на наличие куков,которые пользователь получает при авторизации. С этой целью написал скрипт,который срабатывает при загрузки страницы(его можно увидеть выше). Однако работает это коряво и мне кажется, что у реакта должны быть средства для работы с такими вещами. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать такой переход?

Comment: Хранить флаг авторизации в store и выводить в корневом `render()` либо один компонент, либо другой, не?

Comment: store-вы имеете в виду концепцию Redux?Я его не использовал(

Comment: Ну в state корневого элемента.

Comment: у меня нет корневого элемента. есть 2 похожих .js и все. вы имеете в виду написать какой-то файл-parent в который импортировать app1 и app2, в нем делать проверку и подбрасывать один из них, в зависимости от флага?

Comment: Да, вроде того.

Comment: попробую.Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повозившись со всем этим безобразием, я поднял документацию рутера и обнаружил там метод onEnter. Он может пустить пользователя или не пустить на определенные страницы в зависимости от того, авторизировался ли тот, или нет. Я сделал 1 рутер, в котором прописал руты на страницы приложений. При аутентификации юзера в случае успеха происходит следующее:

```
onSuccess: function (data) {

        const token = config.tokenName
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        this.context.router.push("/main");
    },
```

в файле с самим рутером сделал следующую функцию:

```
function authCheck(nextState,replace) {
        const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (token === 'my_token') {              
        } else {
          replace('/');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Написать один родительский компонент. И проверяйте авторизацию в главном компоненте в `componentDidMount`, если вы не используете flux

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({isAuthorized: document.cookie.indexOf('cookie')===0});
}
```

И в `render` показываете то или иное в зависимости от значение `this.state.isAuthorized`

Comment: идею понял. возник такой вопрос. в главном файле каждого из 2 компонентов есть рутеры, которые подключаются так как тут написано https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router  то есть рутер каждого компонента сслается на один и тот же див в рендере. как в моем случае,когда надо подставлять тот или иной компонент их перепесать?ведь родительский компонент,где я буду делать проверку и подстановку будет ссылаться на тот же див,что и оба рутера